# How to record video from Front Facing Camera?

Tags: android, video-capture

we got a requirement to record video from front and rear cameras simultaniously..
In the Android 2.1 SDK we only have the MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA and DEFAULT, but not FRONT_CAMERA and REAR_CAMERA. So, is there any other way to record from Front camera.. like any third party API's.. 
thank you..

Answer (score 3):

I only know of two devices that have a front camera and that are on 2.1 or that were on 2.1 (EVO and Epic in the US from Sprint). Sprint actually packages the front facing camera in a vendor specific lib that you can lookup via reflection. They describe the process for their specific library in section 3.4 of their developer documentation (https://docs.google.com/View?id=dhtsnvs6_57d2hpqtgr) I suspect other vendors do the same in their BSP.