# How to record video in front camera using surfaceview

Tags: android, android-camera

I am going on with the surfaceview camera to record video with the front camera but causes me error as failed to open searched a lot but can't able to fix i had declared all the permission in manifest but it opens for camera facing back and recordes the video i don't know where it goes wrong.

If anyone have idea about this please help me friends.

Comment: Show the code you're using to open the camera.  See also `openCamera()` in https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

You should find the number of cameras in your device.

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503007/3864698 
and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7847349/3864698